# proper use of MPI and std::string

Tags: c++, c++11, mpi

What would be the proper way of using `std::string` with mpi send and mpi recv commands?

I have a master slave model setup where the master would first load a fairly large amount of strings from a database,I have them stored in memory in a `vector<string>` container,I want to  then send them to the slaves one at a time to compute a text analysis. I originally wrote my  text analysis function to accept a string as an input argument.

Should I have the master convert the string to `const char*` and the slave convert it back to string for computation? Or should i just send string `s.c_str()` as a message buffer? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you thought about using `boost::mpi`? I think it should be fairly easy with that.

Comment: @bamboon it is much easier with `boost::mpi` but its lacking some other features that I may need in the future, the first example is actually sending and receiving a string awesome

Comment: @bamboon using boost mpi the problem becomes porting this original mpi tutorial http://www.lam-mpi.org/tutorials/one-step/ezstart.php

Comment: I only used it for some quick toying recently and found the boost tutorials pretty good. Maybe start with them and then try to translate other stuff yourself. You should be able to avoid a lot of boilerplate code with boost.

Comment: `boost::mpi` has a fairly good coverage of the MPI-1 functionality. In principle mixing with the regular C API should be possible in order to use the features not covered.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to first send the size of the vector/string to the slave processes. Then you can allocate the required memory in the slave processes. In the second pass you can again send all the vectors.